# Conditional gitconfig on a per-directory basis is not working

Tags: git, ubuntu-16.04

In my personal Ubuntu machine I have a directory in which I'll include all my professional projects. I want to use a different git config for them (mainly a different user name and e-mail). This seemed to work before but it is not working any more.

**~/.gitconfig**

```
[user]
    email = personal@email.me
    name = personalname
[core]
    preloadindex = true
    trustctime = false
[includeIf "gitdir:~/professional/"]
    path = ~/professional/gitconfig
```

---

**~/professional/gitconfig**

```
[user]
    email = corporate@email.corp
    name = corporatename
[core]
    preloadindex = true
    trustctime = false
```

---

Whenever I initiated/cloned a git repository in `~/professional` I would have my corporate name and e-mail set up in the configuration of that repository. This is not the case any more for new repositories: there is no trace of the professional config parameters when doing `git config --list` in them; instead, my personal e-mail and user name are set. I do not know what, if anything, I have changed to prevent it from working.

---

**Environment**

- Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
- git version 2.7.4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`includeif` was added in [git 2.13](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.13.0.txt#L127). Consider upgrading.

Comment: Ah, that was it! I have no idea how I managed to roll back my git version without realising, but this solved it, thanks!

Comment: Thanks! my problem was that I read 2.13 as 2.1.3 and wondering how it could be newer than my 2.7.4